# Get jars defined in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have received a J2EE project which has some servlets defined.

I have imported this project in Eclipse [Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)] as a Java project.

This project has a pom.xml defined which contains a list of dependencies. How can pull the dependencies defined in pom.xml.

When I open pom.xml it opens as a raw xml.

Do I need to import this project as a Maven project?

Comment: Yes or you have to convert it into a maven project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: On the command line, you could use: mvn dependency:tree which prints the dependency tree of your maven project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the m2e plugin (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) installed into eclipse , you can import the project as a maven project and then run the dependencies by running as a maven build. Guess that will be the easiest to do.